# Como contar a quantidade de ocorrência de uma substring dentro de uma string?

Tags: java, string, regex

Eu tenho o seguinte retorno:

> EXCEPTION,ClassException,EXCEPTION,Mensagem de Exceção

Eu gostaria de pegar a quantidade de vezes que aparece a String `EXCEPTION` utilizando *Regex*.

Utilizei o seguinte código:

```java
Pattern.compile("(EXCEPTION)",Pattern.DOTALL).matcher(aString).groupCount()
```

Mas o mesmo me retorna `1`. Alguém sabe o que pode ser feito?

Observação: Eu sei que é possível realizar o *parse* e contar a quantidade em um *loop*.

Existe alguma forma melhor do que citei para resolver este problema?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use isto:

```java
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

public int calcCaracter(String MinhaString, String Char){

   int qtd = StringUtils.countMatches(MinhaString, Char);

   return qtd;

}
```

Comment: Essa classe StringUtils é de qual pacote?

Comment: Adicionei na resposta!

Comment: Muito obrigado, utilizei StringUtils.countOccurrencesOf do pacote org.springframework.util.StringUtils.

Comment: As ordens chefia!!!

Answer (score 5):

O método `groupCount()` retorna a quantidade de grupos da expressão, que no caso é um.

Você precisa percorrer o `Matcher` até o final da String, assim:

```java
String aString = "EXCEPTION,ClassException,EXCEPTION,Mensagem de Exceção";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(EXCEPTION)",Pattern.DOTALL).matcher(aString);
int quantidade = 0;
while (m.find()) quantidade++;
System.out.println(quantidade); // saída: 2
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.